# datepicker value in mysql

Tags: posts, customization, jquery, datepicker

I am using a plugin WP-Types for custom post types in which there is a option to create custom fields in which i created one date field for my requirement. Now what happens when i add any date into it .. It will store some kind of wired value ( for me ) in mysql as 14234233 something similar. I have attached a image which have those value in mysql.

Can you please tell me how i am able to achieve that value if i submit it from Jquery datepicker from frontend .

I am inserting values from front-end.

Thanks in advance ![image: ![Attaced Image for reference]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9cWJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [UNIX timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) - with PHP, you can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it like so:

```
echo date( 'd/m/Y', $timestamp ); // day/month/year
```